# Tool that scans and finds DLLs that have been deemed vulnerable

Tags: windows, security

Is there a tool that scans files (local or remote) and detects if an outdated/vulnerable DLL (MS or other known org) exists?

Comment: I think in this situation the best way is to use DLL-files fixer.